# Automating Wi-Fi Calling or Airplane mode toggle with Tasker

Tags: wi-fi, calls, tasker, airplane-mode

I am absolutely 100% new to Tasker. I have bought and installed this app to automate a few things which IFTTT simply can't.

Here is the situation:

My bedroom is in a basement apartment and so I do not get good cell service reception at all while I'm down there, and since it doubles as my office space (on days I work from home) and my gaming area, I tend to spend a decent amount of my time in my room. This being said, I have an LG V30 ThinQ with Android 8.x Oreo and my current service provider offers a Wi-Fi Calling service. Naturally, I turned it on, and bingo... calls are now crisp and text messages sent without a hitch. Well... that's at home at least.

However, at my work, the opposite is true: The Wi-Fi is bad, but the cell service reception is always super strong. Yes, my phone does have a setting to use Wi-Fi calling as a second priority to my cell service (meaning that it will use my cell service before using the Wi-Fi Calling) but instead of switching intelligently based on the strength of the cell service reception strength, it only switches to Wi-Fi Calling once I stop having cell service reception period. Which doesn't work well in the basement, since sometimes I get just enough signal to toggle it back to the bad cell service for calling.

**So, I would like to create a task with Tasker that**, once connected to/disconnected from my home network, would allow either the Wi-Fi Calling to be toggled; or for the airplane mode to be toggled. That way, as long as I'm connected to my home network, my phone will be using the Wi-Fi calling capabilities, without having to toggle them on and off again manually.

The problem is since I'm new to this, I don't know the first thing about programming a task in this version of Tasker. All tutorials I came across were very little help.

Could somebody work me through setting up something along those lines?

Answer (score 0):

Create a profile "Home" with state "Wi-Fi Connected" and SSID set to your home Wi-Fi  network name.

On the profile create a task that

1. Turns on Airplane Mode
2. turns on Wi-Fi

This will be triggered when *connected* to your home network.

On the same profile create an exit task that

1. Turns off Airplane Mode

This will be triggered when *disconnected* to your home network.

Finally set your Wi-Fi Calling preference to "Cellular Network Preferred" (or whatever it is on your phone).

Comment: The task action that turns on Airplane mode, when run by itself, gives an error message and it is unclear how to give Tasker adequate permission to change Airplane mode.